# Symfony2 services with or without state

Tags: php, symfony, service, controller

Pretty new to Symfony2, I've been reading that [services in Symfony2 should be stateless](https://igor.io/2013/03/31/stateless-services.html), and I think it kind of makes sense.

On the other hand, I'm trying to refactor a massive 250-line `SomeController->listAction()`, which creates a table of data with many filters, and 4 forms in total. In order to create all that stuff, the `listAction()` calls a lot of services `FiltersManager`, `UserManager`, `ApiFetcher`, `Paginator`, etc...

I want to move out (almost) all the code from `listAction` to some `MyUsefulClass`, and for that I need that class to have state. So I can see 2 options:

- Create `MyUsefulClass` as a custom model class, but I need to manually create new instances of the services.
- Define `MyUsefulClass` as a service so I can inject all other services, but I need to give that service a state.

I'd go for the 2nd option, but I don't know if I'm missing some other options, and I'm not even sure whether it's really important to keep stateless services...

Comment: Sometime yes, i write stateful service too... you must check che service state every method you expose (as example: if was called the method for set data before you process). BTW yes, sametime you can't solve same situation without do this or with a lot of little service that depends each other. My two cents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up creating the classes that do the job as services, because I think services are one of the best things about Symfony in many ways (they have some issues though).

In order to keep my services stateless, what I did was to create another set of classes, pretty much just value objects with some properties. These values objects hold the state I need and they are passed to (and/or returned from) the methods in my services.

This approach makes me write more classes, but it makes sense to me, and I can clearly separate the code that does the job from the code that just holds some property values.